# How to order entries by vote?

Tags: mysql

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entries` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` text,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


id title date
1  aaa   2016-09-15 19:00:00
2  bbb   2016-09-14 19:00:00
3  ccc   2016-09-13 19:00:00
4  ddd   2016-09-12 19:00:00
5  eee   2016-09-11 19:00:00


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `votes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_entry` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

id id_entry
1  1
2  1 
3  1
4  2
5  3
```

I need a way to order all entries by vote and then by date, So I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(entries.id) as totvotes, entries.id, entries.date FROM entries LEFT JOIN votes ON entries.id=votes.id_entry GROUP by entries.id ORDER by totvotes DESC, entries.date DESC
```

And the result is this:

```
totvotes entries.id entries.date
3        1          2016-09-15 19:00:00
1        2          2016-09-15 19:00:00
1        3          2016-09-15 19:00:00
1        4          2016-09-15 19:00:00
1        5          2016-09-15 19:00:00
```

As you can see, the query show totvotes=1 for entries without vote ( 4 and 5 ). How can I avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count `votes.id_entry` instead of this `SELECT COUNT(entries.id)`.

So try with this: `SELECT COUNT(votes.id_entry) as totvotes...`

**Some subtleties regarding `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT COUNT(0);   Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(-1);  Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(NULL); Result: 0

SELECT COUNT(71); Result: 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0)